# Analyzing the Schrodinger equation under Lorentz and Galilean transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, invariants

I'm trying to see what happens to the Schrodinger equation under Lorentz and Galilean transformation. So I assumed a free Schrödinger wave with the form: $$\psi = A e^{i(\omega t - kx)} ~.$$ A Galilei transformation turns this into: $$\psi = A e^{i(\omega t' - k(x'+vt'))} = A e^{i((\omega -kv) t' - kx')} ~.$$ So $$\omega' = \omega - kv$$ and $$k'=k ~.$$

Now if we apply a Lorentz transformation, it turns the equation into: $$\psi = A e^{i(\omega t' - k \gamma (x'+vt'))} = A e^{i((\omega -\gamma kv) t' - \gamma kx')} ~.$$ So $$\omega' = \omega - \gamma kv$$ and $$k'=\gamma k ~.$$

My first question is, is my assumption correct? In other words, *can I just assume a free Schrödinger wave and apply the transformations and deduce if the same is true for the Schrödinger equation?*

My second question is, *does this prove that Schrödinger equation is invariant under Galilean transformation and not invariant under Lorentz transformation?*

Comment: It does not, in fact, make sense to use an analysis of a special case to deduce something about a general statement.

Comment: I did suspect that my method is not correct. What approach should I take then?

Comment: If you wish to understand how the Schro equation transforms for a given Hamiltonian, then transform the equation. For a relativistic QM, it would likely be better to just find a book...any QFT book should be fine but if you're willing to slog through it, Weinberg's volume 1 would be particularly direct in setting up this matter.

Comment: @RichardMyers first, one can use a special case to prove that the equation is not invariant, as if an equation is invariant, it will be invariant in all cases. Second, it is not a special case, a wave function can be rewritten in terms of plane waves using Fourier transform. So indeed one can try to use this approach also to proove that an equation is invariant.

Comment: @GiorgioBusoni Obviously a counter-example is sufficient to prove a claim false. However, your other two statements here are, themselves, completely false or inapplicable. To your first claim: what is being done here is not showing an equation is invariant, it is looking at some properties of a particular function. This implies nothing about the Schro equation. To your second claim, yes, of course most nice functions can be expanded in terms of Fourier modes. But that is a statement about functions. It has absolutely nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Comment: @RichardMyers I think that one of us did not understand what he was trying to do. Maybe I was over-interpreting what we was doing. But I saw in his post the first step to prove the invariance. The second step is to fourier-transform the equation, and the third to substitute the relations found here in the transformed disperision relation and see if it is still verified. This procedure IS indeed correct. But as I said, maybe I was over-interpreting

Answer (score -2):

Shroedinger equation assumes the relation

$E=\frac{p^2}{2m}$

where $E$ is energy, $m$ is mass and $p$ momentum of a particle. This relation is valid in Newton/classical mechanics, but not in special relativity, so the second transformation does not keep the equation invariant.
Now try to apply the equation to your wave solution and see if it is invariant under galileian transformation, or ue the relation abobe to get the same answer

Comment: These claims are false. The Schro equation makes no claims about the form of the Hamiltonian (energy) and indeed makes perfect sense even in a relativistic context, assuming that the Hamiltonian actually comes from a relativistic theory (so there is some 4-momentum operator on the Hilbert space).

Comment: @RichardMyers remains to see what you call schro equation. The original equation derived by Schroedinger indeed used classical mechanics operator. The generalization came later one, and by that time relativistioc corrections were used to derive other equations, like Klein-Gordon. I usually refer to the Schro equation as the original one, strictly classical. Indeed, I think the General version was not even derived by Schroe.

Comment: Only $i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\psi\rangle = H|\psi\rangle$ bears the name "Schro" equation in the modern parlance. To call anything else by the same name is entirely misleading in the year 2021. Furthermore, the Klein-Gordon equation is not an equation of motion for the state of a relativistic system. This was historically a point of confusion, but has been well-understood in excess of 50 years now.

Comment: I think what deserves what name is a matter of opinions, not facts, not science.

Comment: It is a matter of communication, which *does* matter. If I began speaking of birds and then pointed to a picture of a dog, you would be rightly confused. Saying "what I call a bird is a matter of opinion" would only be accurate in the most superficial sense.

Comment: Well, I guess the only thing that would matter would be knowing what equation was referring to the original author of the post. The rest of the discussion is off-topic.